# Queria saber como passar um registro de um array de uma página php para outra e então para uma tabela sql

Tags: php, html, mysql

Gostaria de saber como passar um registro do array de uma página php para outra página php que vai, então, dar um insert na tabela correspondente no banco de dados, sou iniciante em php e já tentei de várias formas mas sem sucesso. (PS: quero passar da página carrinho.php para finalizar.php) (OBS: também aceito outras sugestões de como passar os dados sem ser por array)

Meu código atualmente está assim:

Minha tabela:

```
CREATE TABLE pedido (
id_pedido int not null AUTO_INCREMENT,
id_empresa int not null,
data_pedido varchar(15) not null,
data_entrega varchar(15) not null,
estado int not null,
data_vencimento varchar(45),
CONSTRAINT pk_ped PRIMARY KEY (id_pedido),
CONSTRAINT fk_ped FOREIGN KEY (id_empresa) REFERENCES empresa (id_empresa)
);
```

carrinho.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

if (!isset($_SESSION['tudo'])) {
  $_SESSION['tudo'] = array();
}

if (isset($_GET['add']) && $_GET['add'] == 'carrinho') {

  $idProduto = $_GET['id_residuo'];
  if (!isset($_SESSION['tudo'][$idProduto])) {
    $_SESSION['tudo'][$idProduto] = 1;
  } else {
    $_SESSION['tudo'][$idProduto] += 1;
  }
}
?>

<html lang="pt-br">

<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8" />
<head>

<body>

    <table>
      <thead>
        <tr>
          <th> Nome do Residuo </th>
          <th> Quantidade </th>
          <th> Preco Unitário R$ </th>
          <th> Total </th>
          <th> Remover </th>
        </tr>
      </thead>
      <?php
      if (count($_SESSION['tudo']) == 0) {
        echo 'Carrinho Vazio';
      } else {
        try {

          $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_reuse', "root", "");
          $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
        } catch (PDOException $ex) {
          echo "ERRO: " . $ex->getMessage();
          exit;
        }

        $idEmpresa = $_SESSION['id_empresa'] + 0;


        $_SESSION['dados'] = array();
        $estado = "0";
        $tudo = 0;
        $quantidadeTotal = 0;

        foreach ($_SESSION['tudo'] as $idProduto => $quantidade) {

          $select = $pdo->prepare("SELECT * FROM residuo WHERE id_residuo = ?");
          $select->bindParam(1, $idProduto);
          $select->execute();
          $residuos = $select->fetchAll();
          $total = $quantidade * $residuos[0]["valor_residuo"];
          $tudo += $total;
          $valor = $residuos[0]["valor_residuo"] + 0.0;
          $quantidadeTotal += $quantidade;
          $dataP = date('d-m-Y');
          $dataE = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 week'));
          $dataV = date('d-m-Y', strtotime('+1 month'));
          echo
          '<tr>
            <td>  ' . $residuos[0]["nome_residuo"] . ' </td> <br />
            <td>  ' . $quantidade . ' </td> <br />
            <td>  ' . number_format($residuos[0]["valor_residuo"], 2, ",", ".") . ' </td> <br />
            <td>  ' . number_format($total, 2, ",", ".") . ' </td> <br/>
            <td>  <a href="remover.php?remover=carrinho&id_residuo=' . $idProduto . '"> Remover </a> </td>
          </tr>';

          array_push(
            $_SESSION['dados'],
            array(
              'id_empresa' => $idEmpresa,
              'data_vencimento' => $dataV,
              'data_pedido' => $dataP,
              'data_entrega' => $dataE,
              'estado' => $estado,
              'quantidade_item' => $quantidade,
              'valor_item' => $valor
            )
          );
        }
      ?>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="5"> <?php echo '<a href="finalizar.php"> Finalizar Pedido </a>' ?> </th>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3"> Valor Total </th>
          <td colspan="2"> <?php echo number_format($tudo, 2, ",", ".") ?> </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <th colspan="3"> Quantidade Total </th>
          <td colspan="2"> <?php echo $quantidadeTotal ?> </td>
        </tr>
      <?php
      }
      ?>

    </table>

</body>

</html>
```

finalizar.php:

```
<?php
session_start();

try {
    $pdo = new PDO('mysql:host=localhost;dbname=bd_reuse', "root", "");
    $pdo->setAttribute(PDO::ATTR_ERRMODE, PDO::ERRMODE_EXCEPTION);
} catch (PDOException $ex) {
    echo "ERRO: " . $ex->getMessage();
    exit;
}//fim conexao


$insert = $pdo->prepare("INSERT INTO pedido (id_empresa, data_pedido, data_entrega, estado, 
data_vencimento) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?, ?)");
$insert->bindParam(1, $_SESSION['dados']['id_empresa']);
$insert->bindParam(2, $_SESSION['dados']['data_pedido']);
$insert->bindParam(3, $_SESSION['dados']['data_entrega']);
$insert->bindParam(4, $_SESSION['dados']['estado']);
$insert->bindParam(5, $_SESSION['dados']['data_vencimento']);
$insert->execute();
?>
```

É basicamente isso, desculpe pelo código grande.
Agradeço pela paciência e eu agradeço demais quem puder ajudar pois estou realmente precisando disso funcionando.

Comment: Não faz muito sentido isso... Os itens do carrinho estarão numa tabela, quando clicar em finalizar você recupera esses itens sem precisar passar de uma página para outra

Comment: Concordo com @PapaCharlie, mantenha uma tabela com os pedidos dos clientes(carrinho de compras), acontece de clientes inicializarem uma transação de compra em um dispositivo e terminar em outro. Se utilizar o dispositivo cliente para armazenar ou rotear esses dados ele fica restrito a finalizar a compra apenas nesse dispositivo e navegador e os dados dessa operação podem se perder em caso de falha do equipamento do cliente ou limpeza de  memória do browser.

Answer (score -1):

Então pelo que eu sei a maneira mais facil fazer isso seria você armazenar os dados do array num COOKIE e depois recuper essa informações na outra página no caso "finalizar.php", lembrando que os COOKIES ficam armazenados no cliente ou seja no navegador do usuário, mas para essa situação se encaixa perfeitamento porque creio que você queira apenas passar essas informações para outra página para depois transferilas para o banco de dados. Se voce nao souber utilizar COOKIES e só pesquisar ou ir na documentação e bastante simples de usar.